# Facebook account kit

Tags: android, ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-account-kit

This is the first time I'm going to use Facebook account kit to verify mobile numbers. My query is, can I verify the mobile numbers that are not linked with any Facebook account ?  I have checked all over the internet on this but wasn't able to get any proper answers or responses. Any suggestions on this is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“Because Account Kit does not link phone or email login credentials to Facebook accounts, […]”_ _“If you develop your app with version 4.17 of the Facebook SDK for Android, and people have the latest Facebook app, version 99, installed on their mobile device, Account Kit can use instant verification for telephone numbers. In this case, if people have a Facebook account containing the number they enter, Account Kit verifies the number directly without requiring them to manually enter an SMS code.”_ - sounds to me as if a Facebook account was not a requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your response bro..  do you mean to say that I can use it to verify mobile numbers instead of a 3rd party API service like Nexmo, Twilio etc.?

Comment: I am not sure, that’s just how I would interpret the quoted parts. You’ll need to either test it, or ask Facebook if you want to know for certain.

Comment: Okie man ! Thanks for your response. I'll check them out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify and phone number through Account Kit that has a supported country code (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/countrycodes). They do not have to be on a Facebook Account. Accounts created with Account Kit are in no way linked to Facebook Accounts. Instant Verification (referenced in comment above), is used to verify a phone number on a given device, but no link between that Account Kit account and Facebook account is created.